# C++Winrt How to throw an exception from an async method

Tags: uwp, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, c++-winrt, winrt-async

I have following code

```
IAsyncOperation<bool> trythiswork()
    {
        bool contentFound{ false };
        try
        {
            auto result = co_await someAsyncFunc();
            if (result)
            {
                throw;
                contentFound = true;
            }
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            LOG_CAUGHT_EXCEPTION();
        }
    }
```

But the catch block is never executed even when control goes to throw statement after the if condition is met. And control goes to `contentFound = true;` after the throw.
Is there something wrong with how I am throwing from this method? Can you help me in throwing from this async method? I am expecting that catch block will be executed and the line `contentFound = true;` will not be executed. Thanks

Comment: Performing a `throw;` when not inside a `catch` results in a call to `std::terminate`.

Comment: You cannot `throw;` unless you are currently handling an exception, i.e. you are in a `catch` block. Regardless, you can throw exceptions from a co-routine the same way you throw exceptions from any other functions. The C++/WinRT library makes sure the exception re-surfaces at the outer `co_await` operator.